# D3 Canvas force layout - disjointed group replelling the other group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a set of nodes (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K) but connected to each other in 2 disjointed groups (A,B,C) and (D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="connect1();">
    <canvas width="300" height="100"></canvas>
    <!--button id="ref" onclick="refresh()">refresh </button-->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      width = canvas.width,
      height = canvas.height;
    var links =[] , nodes = [] ;

    var graph={nodes,links}, wsConn;    

function connect1(){

    addNodeCanvas("A", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("B", "6");
    addNodeCanvas("C", "4");
    addNodeCanvas("D", "2");
    addNodeCanvas("E", "3");
 addNodeCanvas("F", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("G", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("H", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("I", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("J", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("K", "1");
 
    addLinkCanvas("A","B");
    addLinkCanvas("A","C");

 
    addLinkCanvas("E","D");
 addLinkCanvas("F","D");
 addLinkCanvas("G","D");
 addLinkCanvas("H","D");
 addLinkCanvas("I","D");
 addLinkCanvas("J","D");
 addLinkCanvas("K","D");

    refresh();
}


var nodeColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20);

function addNodeCanvas(nodeName,g) {
  var node = {
    x: 400,
    y: 400,
    id: nodeName,
    grp:g
  };
  var n = nodes.push(node);
}


function addLinkCanvas(idSrc, idTarget) {

    if (idSrc != idTarget) {
    var s = {},
      t = {};
    nodes.forEach(function(curNode) {
      if (typeof curNode.id != "undefined") {
        if (curNode.id == idSrc) {
          s = curNode;
        }
        if (curNode.id == idTarget) {
          t = curNode;
        }
      }
    });

    links.push({
      source: s,
      target: t
    });
  };

}




    function refresh() {

            var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { 
                return d.id; 
            }))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

        simulation
            .nodes(nodes)
            .on("tick", ticked)
            .force("link")
            .links(links);
        d3.select(canvas)
            .call(d3.drag()
                .container(canvas)
                .subject(dragsubject)
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));


        function ticked() {
            var margin = 20;
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.x = Math.max(margin, Math.min(width - margin, d.x))
                d.y = Math.max(margin, Math.min(height - margin, d.y))
            });

            function dblclick() {
                nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.fx = d.fy = null;
                })
            };
            context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            context.beginPath();
            links.forEach(drawLink);
            context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            nodes.forEach(drawNode);

        }

        function dragsubject() {
            return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
        }
        var clickDate = new Date();
        var difference_ms;

        function dragstarted() {
            
        }

        function dragged() {
           
        }


        function dragended() {
           
        }


        function drawLink(d) {
            context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
            context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
        }

        var nodeColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20),
            labelColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green', 'purple']);

        function drawNode(d) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(d.x + 10, d.y);
            context.arc(d.x, d.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
            context.stroke();
            context.fillStyle = nodeColors(d.grp);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
            context.beginPath();
            context.font = (d.labelSize ? d.labelSize : 10) + 'px Arial';
            context.fillStyle = labelColors(d.grp);
            context.fillText(d.id ? d.id : d.grp, d.x, d.y);
            context.closePath();
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Since these 2 groups are disjointed after loading the page they start repelling each other and keep pushing until it reaches the end of the canvas.

How to avoid this thing so that the 2 groups stay away from each other but still remains around the center of the canvas.

> Please try it running a few times, and you will see nodes A,B & C getting pushed to the end and remain there in a straight line.

Comment: If I run your snippet I have a stable image, no slow moving of the groups. Also not after dragging some nodes. Are you able to add some attraction/gravity towards the center of the canvas?

Comment: Please try now, added more nodes to 2nd group so that it can push the first group

Comment: I first assumed a group got pushed out of the visible part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `forceCenter` looks not strong enough so I replaced it with a set of `forceX()` and `forceY()` forces.

By setting a maximum distance for the manybody the push is limited and by increasing the strength it still repels at close distance.

You specify a link `id` function but you set the `source` and `target` not equal to the `id`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="connect1();">
    <canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <!--button id="ref" onclick="refresh()">refresh </button-->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      width = canvas.width,
      height = canvas.height;
    var links =[] , nodes = [] ;

    var graph={nodes,links}, wsConn;

function connect2(){

    addNodeCanvas("A", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("B", "6");
    addNodeCanvas("C", "4");
    addNodeCanvas("D", "2");
    addNodeCanvas("E", "3");
   addNodeCanvas("F", "1");
 
    addLinkCanvas("A","B");
    addLinkCanvas("A","C");
 
    addLinkCanvas("E","D");
   addLinkCanvas("F","D");

    refresh();
}

function connect1(){

    addNodeCanvas("A", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("B", "6");
    addNodeCanvas("C", "4");
    addNodeCanvas("D", "2");
    addNodeCanvas("E", "3");
    addNodeCanvas("F", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("G", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("H", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("I", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("J", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("K", "1");

    addLinkCanvas("A","B");
    addLinkCanvas("A","C");


    addLinkCanvas("E","D");
    addLinkCanvas("F","D");
    addLinkCanvas("G","D");
    addLinkCanvas("H","D");
    addLinkCanvas("I","D");
    addLinkCanvas("J","D");
    addLinkCanvas("K","D");

    refresh();
}

var nodeColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20);

function addNodeCanvas(nodeName,g) {
  var node = {
    x: 400,
    y: 400,
    id: nodeName,
    grp:g
  };
  var n = nodes.push(node);
}


function addLinkCanvas_1(idSrc, idTarget) {

    if (idSrc != idTarget) {
        var s = {},
        t = {};
        nodes.forEach(function(curNode) {
        if (typeof curNode.id != "undefined") {
            if (curNode.id == idSrc) { s = curNode; }
            if (curNode.id == idTarget) { t = curNode; }
        }
        });

        links.push({
        source: s,
        target: t
        });
    };
}

function addLinkCanvas(idSrc, idTarget) {

    if (idSrc != idTarget) {
        links.push({
            source: idSrc,
            target: idTarget
        });
    };
}

    function refresh() {

            var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().distanceMax(70).strength(d=>-50))
            // .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width*0.5, height*0.5))
            .force("centerX", d3.forceX(width*0.5).strength(0.02))
            .force("centerY", d3.forceY(height*0.5).strength(0.02));

        simulation
            .nodes(nodes)
            .on("tick", ticked)
            .force("link")
            .links(links);
        d3.select(canvas)
            .call(d3.drag()
                .container(canvas)
                .subject(dragsubject)
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));


        function ticked() {
            var margin = 20;
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.x = Math.max(margin, Math.min(width - margin, d.x))
                d.y = Math.max(margin, Math.min(height - margin, d.y))
            });

            function dblclick() {
                nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.fx = d.fy = null;
                })
            };
            context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            context.beginPath();
            links.forEach(drawLink);
            context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            nodes.forEach(drawNode);

        }

        function dragsubject() {
            return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
        }
        var clickDate = new Date();
        var difference_ms;

        function dragstarted() {
        }

        function dragged() {
        }

        function dragended() {
        }

        function drawLink(d) {
            context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
            context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
        }

        var nodeColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20),
            labelColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green', 'purple']);

        function drawNode(d) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(d.x + 10, d.y);
            context.arc(d.x, d.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
            context.stroke();
            context.fillStyle = nodeColors(d.grp);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
            context.beginPath();
            context.font = (d.labelSize ? d.labelSize : 10) + 'px Arial';
            context.fillStyle = labelColors(d.grp);
            context.fillText(d.id ? d.id : d.grp, d.x, d.y);
            context.closePath();
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes from the fact that once the initial repulsion force is applied, no other force comes into play to counteract it. So the movement persists until the borders of the canvas container, where nodes hit the wall (which is equivalent to a [normal force](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force) and which brings equilibrium).

To make the infinite repulsion movement stop, you need a [viscosity force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) which will progressively slow down the groups of nodes until they reach a zero speed.

d3's force layout provides a parameter for that: [velocityDecay](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_velocityDecay):

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .velocityDecay(0.8); // the velocity decay setting
```

You can play with the value of `velocityDecay` which can be between 0 and 1, where 0 is equivalent to not applying the setting (no viscosity) and 1 is equivalent to having a normal force and no movement to start with.

For instance with a viscosity of 0.8:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="connect1();">
<canvas width="500" height="350"></canvas>
<!--button id="ref" onclick="refresh()">refresh </button-->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height;
  var links =[] , nodes = [] ;

  var graph={nodes,links}, wsConn;

  function connect1(){

    addNodeCanvas("A", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("B", "6");
    addNodeCanvas("C", "4");
    addNodeCanvas("D", "2");
    addNodeCanvas("E", "3");
    addNodeCanvas("F", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("G", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("H", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("I", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("J", "1");
    addNodeCanvas("K", "1");

    addLinkCanvas("A","B");
    addLinkCanvas("A","C");


    addLinkCanvas("E","D");
    addLinkCanvas("F","D");
    addLinkCanvas("G","D");
    addLinkCanvas("H","D");
    addLinkCanvas("I","D");
    addLinkCanvas("J","D");
    addLinkCanvas("K","D");

    refresh();
  }


  var nodeColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20);

  function addNodeCanvas(nodeName,g) {
    var node = {
      x: width / 2,
      y: height / 2,
      id: nodeName,
      grp:g
    };
    var n = nodes.push(node);
  }


  function addLinkCanvas(idSrc, idTarget) {

    if (idSrc != idTarget) {
      var s = {},
        t = {};
      nodes.forEach(function(curNode) {
        if (typeof curNode.id != "undefined") {
          if (curNode.id == idSrc) {
            s = curNode;
          }
          if (curNode.id == idTarget) {
            t = curNode;
          }
        }
      });

      links.push({
        source: s,
        target: t
      });
    };

  }




  function refresh() {

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .velocityDecay(0.8);

    simulation
    .nodes(nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked)
    .force("link")
    .links(links);
    d3.select(canvas)
    .call(d3.drag()
    .container(canvas)
    .subject(dragsubject)
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));


    function ticked() {
      var margin = 20;
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x = Math.max(margin, Math.min(width - margin, d.x))
        d.y = Math.max(margin, Math.min(height - margin, d.y))
      });

      function dblclick() {
        nodes.forEach(function(d) {
          d.fx = d.fy = null;
        })
      };
      context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      context.beginPath();
      links.forEach(drawLink);
      context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
      context.stroke();
      context.beginPath();
      nodes.forEach(drawNode);

    }

    function dragsubject() {
      return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
    }
    var clickDate = new Date();
    var difference_ms;

    function dragstarted() {

    }

    function dragged() {

    }


    function dragended() {

    }


    function drawLink(d) {
      context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
      context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
    }

    var nodeColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20),
      labelColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green', 'purple']);

    function drawNode(d) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(d.x + 10, d.y);
      context.arc(d.x, d.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
      context.stroke();
      context.fillStyle = nodeColors(d.grp);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
      context.beginPath();
      context.font = (d.labelSize ? d.labelSize : 10) + 'px Arial';
      context.fillStyle = labelColors(d.grp);
      context.fillText(d.id ? d.id : d.grp, d.x, d.y);
      context.closePath();
    }
  }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Xavier, learnt something new and implemented in the code, however rioV8's answer has done the trick for my problem.